# Redactor Rails renders multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, redactor

I've successfully installed the gem 'redactor'rails' and can call it in a form, and update a note successfully.

**Problem:** When creating a post, the form renders multiple input areas. When I update/edit an existing post, the more times I click "Edit", more input areas are rendered. Why does it render multiple fields?

### [image: New Note w/ Multiple Inputs]

[image: Edit note w/ Multiple Inputs]

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @note do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content, :input_html => { :class => "redactor" }
  = f.button :submit, class: "button"
```

Comment: Update: When you refresh either view, the problem is solved.
None the less, this is still a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should destroy old instances of Redactor for each selector before initializing it.

`$('.redactor').redactor('core.destroy');`